# Callback and return with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, callback

I am stuck with a problem here, where I want to keep my functions separately (in files) for a neater code.

In my Route.js, I am calling a function like this:

```
app.post('/pay', function(req, res){
    User.getPaypal(function(output){ 
        console.log(output) //i am not getting this result(output)
    })
})
```

The function is exported in another file as below:

```
module.exports.getPaypal = function(){
    var create_payment_json= {
        //some values
    };

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (err, payment) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {
             return payment;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to get a return value of payment or err as a return for the called function in the route.

How can I make this work?

Comment: what you are getting in `console.log(output)` ?

Comment: I actually want to get the return value of payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with understanding concept of [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) which is based on concept of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

As for your problem you were missing the use of passed callback function. It should be as below

```
module.exports.getPaypal = function(callback){ //callback argument was missing
    var create_payment_json= {
        //some values
    };

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (err, payment) {
        if (err) {
            callback(undefined, err); // callback function being invoked
        } else {
            callback(payment, undefined); // would be better if you have two arguments to callback first for result second for error
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's step back and consider the basics of how functions work.

Let's assume you wrote the function:

```
function double () {
    var x = 1;
    return x * 2;
}
```

Then you call it as

```
var y = double(100);
```

and you see that `y` is 2 instead of 200?

What would you say is wrong with this?

If you said you've declared `double` to not take an argument, you'd be right. The fix is:

```
function double (x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

Now let's look at your function:

```
var getPaypal = function () {
    /** for now it does not matter what's here **/
}
```

Now you are calling the function as:

```
function mycallback (output) {
    console.log(output);
}

getPaypal(mycallback);
```

I hope you see what's wrong. It's obvious that you've declared the function as:

```
function getPaypal() {}
```

when what you want is:

```
function getPaypal(anotherFunction) {}
```

Now, how do you pass the result to the callback function? Easy, just call it:

```
function getPaypal(anotherFunction) {
    /** some processing **/

    anotherFunction(result); // this is how you pass the result to the callback
}
```

A callback is no different than a number or string or array. It's just something passed to your function.